# How to pass data to a Script Component within an SSIS data flow task?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In SSIS 2008, I am using *Script Components* to generate data and *Union All* to aggregate it. Now, I need this aggregated data to be processed by another script component to generate output to the file.

Script Component itself doesn't have inputs, so the best thing to transfer data to it is to make sure that it is in a variable at the moment the script component's execution starts.

How do I provide input data to a Script component, given that at some point it is in Union All in Data flow task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [Script Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137640(v=sql.105).aspx) most certainly **can** have an input. When you first create a Script Component, you select whether it acts as a data source (outputs only), a data destination (input only), or a transformation (both input and output):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can obviously add a `Script Component` and before placing it, you can choose whether it is a *Source*, *Destination* or a *Transformation*.

When you drag and drop a *Script Component* transformation onto the *Data Flow* tab, the  *Select Script Component Type* dialog will appear. Select the option *Destination* to make the *Script Component* behave like a destination component.

[image: Select Script Component Type]